# Is this a good reason to check types in Python?

Tags: python, typechecking

I know that checking types in Python is bad and you should probably never do it. But I can't seem to find the disadvantage to this.

```
class O(object):         
    def __init__(self, name):
        '''Can only be called in derived classes.'''
        if type(self) is O:
            message = "%(class)s cannot be instantiated, it must be derived."
            raise TypeError, message % { "class" : O }
        self.name = name

    def fn(self):
        '''Must be populated in derived classes.'''
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now if someone tries to instantiate O, a class I never meant to be instantiated, they know immediately.

Is this still bad form?

Comment: Why don't you want this subclassed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [Abstract Base Classes](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) as they will provide more fine grained control over how the subclasses are instantiated if this is something that you really want to do.

All in all, this might be a valid use because you are not preventing *me* from passing whatever *I* want to your code but I still wouldn't consider it pythonic. You are telling *me* that *I* can't instantiate your class. What If I want to?

Using ABC's, it looks like:

```
import abc

class O(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta     
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def fn(self):
        pass
```

This has the advantage of not breaking super on the `fn` method. As you have it with the `raise NotImplementedError`, you are breaking super for multiple inheritance. If a class derives from two classes that subclass `O` and both call super (as they should to allow for multiple inheritance) then it will create the exception that you raise.

So now, you are not just telling me that I can't instantiate your class, you are telling me that I can't use multiple inheritance when subclassing from your class.

Comment: I edited to show the intent more clearly. I do this often to make the purpose of such a class obvious upon reading the code or trying to use it without understanding it.

Comment: @Cory, based on your update you really do want an ABC. see my update.

Comment: Your example is great, and you've sparked my interest in the abc module. But you've forgotten the last two underscores on __metaclass

Answer (score 5):

Don't check at all, we're are all adults here. Just add a note that `O` shouldn't be instantiated directly, either as a comment and/or in the documentation.

It's the same as if someone would call a method that requires an `int` as its parameter with a `string` instead. If the program crashes, they screwed it up. Otherwise you would need to add type checks to just about everything.

Answer (score 1):

What is that you are trying to achieve with the above code.

In this case self is of type O and will always result in raising the exception.

Look at this snippet to understand it a little better

```
class O(object):         
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name      

o = O("X")

print type(o)
print isinstance(o, O)
if type(o) is O:
    print "Yes"
```

This will output

```
<class '__main__.O'>
True
Yes
```

Comment: it won't raise an exception if you subclass it which is the point

Comment: My code prevents any instances of O from being created with O(), but any class derived from O will be able to instantiate itself.